# JavaScript - Canvas - COLLISIONS

Tags: canvas, javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/emLLq04w/
— хочу обработать столкновения со "стенами", пытался, пытался, пытался... но, ничего нормального не вышло... Допишите, пожалуйста, и объясните, как все это делается, если не трудно. Спасибо!

```js
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  cnv = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = 600;
  canvas.height = 250;
  var x = 10, y = 10;
  var cell_size = 16;
  canvas.width  = 16 * cell_size;
 canvas.height = 16 * cell_size;
 var map = [

[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,2,0,0],
[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

];
 


function init(){
cnv.fillStyle = "#eee";
cnv.fillRect(0,0, 600, 250);
 cnv.fillStyle = "orange";
 for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < 31; j++){
   if(map[i][j] == 1){
    cnv.fillRect(j * cell_size / 2, i * cell_size / 2 + cell_size * 4, cell_size / 2, cell_size / 2); 
   }
  }
 }
}

function player(){

document.onkeydown = function(e){

 if(e.keyCode == 37) x-=5;
 if(e.keyCode == 38) y-=5;
 if(e.keyCode == 39) x+=5;
 if(e.keyCode == 40) y+=5;

  cnv.clearRect(x,y, 20,20);
  init();
  cnv.fillStyle = "#000";
  cnv.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
  if(collision(x)) console.log(111) // просто для проверки
 }
}


function collision(t){
        // обработка столкновений со "стенами"
}


init();
player();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам для начала нужно составить удобную карту этих "стен", а не так, как сейчас у вас - размер ячейки 16 пикселей, размер блока 20 пикселей, шаг 5 пикселей. Вы так, естественно, запутаетесь.

Для начала приравняйте всё к единичному значению - 16 пикселей. 16 пикселей - одна ячейка стены, 16 пикселей - одна ячейка черной точки.

Потом вам очень легко будет найти, происходит ли "столкновение", посмотрите пример:

http://jsfiddle.net/emLLq04w/1/

Зная, где сейчас находится черная точка, можно легко определить по карте, происходит ли столкновение.

Comment: Спасибо! А если, например, я не буду по 16px перемещаться, а по 5, тогда?

Comment: (x /  (x / step - (x / step - cell_size))) - пробовал так, но не получается... не могу отловить эту чертову погрешность..

где step - это шаг который == 5, например